# problem while deploy the node.js application

Tags: node.js, deployment, webdeploy

I am working to deploy my `node app` on the server. I purchased the hosting of NameCheap. I first upload the `node app` on the cPannel then I create the node.js application. I attached the picture that how I create the node application.The node version on the computer is `v16.14.0` and the version I select in my cPannal is `v14.18.3` because the latest version in my cPannal is `v14.18.3` [how I create node app in cPannal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEVWg.png)
I follow all the steps but the message that show when I hit the URL, are shown in the image [message show when We hit the API's URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gifcl.png)

```
const connectToDb = require("./DBconfig");
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');

connectToDb();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT | 5000;
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
connectToDb();

app.use( '/api/user' ,require('./routes/user') );
app.use( '/api/post' ,require('./routes/post') );

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('The site is start now')
})

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'))
  })
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The above code I used in `index.js` but It is not working properly. the domain is [The domain of API is](https://api.yourguide.pk/) 
can anyone tell me that I properly upload/ deploy the application on the server?

Comment: `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`

Comment: I have changed it but it is not working. It shows the same error of `Error 503. Service Unavailable`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

process.env.PORT

make sure to copy it exactly like that because web hostings use the same env variable

Comment: I have changed it but it is not working. It shows the same error of  `Error 503. Service Unavailable`

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be absolutely correct. If there is an issue with the node app itself, you would get an error on startup. If the NodeJS app is running and you are able to access it directly on the port, e.g. your-domain.com:5000 and you get the 503 error only when accessing it over the domain directly, then most probably the issue is related to the web service. If it's Apache setup, make sure to have the following rules inside your .htaccess to forward all requests to your node app:

```
# Add headers to all responses.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Simple URL redirect:
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem `service is unavailable` may occur when you have install some packages globally but the server is restricted to install the packages from the `packege.json` file. so check the packege.json file.